# How to change the dataype of a view

Tags: oracle, view

I use this to create a view

```
    create view v_FASIDE as  
    select
       name as name,
       age as age,
       cast(id as char(3)) as id;
    from DRAYZ;
```

`id` is a `char(3)`. But when I use SQL Developer to see the datatype of `V_FASIDE` is turn out to be `charvar2()` instead of `char`. What is the cause of this? I don't know the version of the database my company is using.

Comment: Looks like you received plenty of answers here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4486094/change-the-datatype-of-a-column-in-views#latest

Answer (score 0):

No such problem when I try it:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vfaside
  2  AS
  3     SELECT ename,
  4            CAST (empno AS CHAR (3)) AS id                     --> this
  5     FROM emp;

View created.

SQL> DESC vfaside
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 ID                                                 CHAR(3)       --> this

SQL>
```

Did you **refresh** data in SQL Developer? Maybe you're looking at something *old*.

---

By the way, what is `charvar2()` supposed to be? Never heard of such a datatype in Oracle. `varchar2`, maybe?

Comment: But when I type
desc v_FASIDE,,it show

Name         Null Type          
------------ ---- ------------- 
id                     VARCHAR2()  
The id show VARCHAR2() instead of CHAR. Do you know what the cause of this

Comment: No idea, sorry. As I said, everything is OK when I tried it.